# OOP inheritance and objects instaces

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

I working out the inheritance and OOPS in JavaScript. I created 'A' object and 'B' object and inherited all the properties of 'B' to 'A'.

While I check the newly created object instance by using 'instanceof', I am getting both objects are true.
But I have created the object using 'B' constructor only.

```
function A(){
    this.a = "test1",
    this.b = "test2"
}

function B(){
    this.c = "test3",
    this.d = "test4"
}

B.prototype = new A();

var userObj = new B();

console.log(userObj instanceof B); // true
console.log(userObj instanceof A); // true, How this can be true?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript, the inheritance is prototype-based. That means that there are no classes. Instead, an object inherits from another object.

What you have done here is, object B inherits from object A because of this:

```
B.prototype = new A();
```

So ,now,  `userObj` (instance of object B) of-course becomes instance of object A, (thats what inheritance is all about, right?)

So thats the reason

```
console.log(userObj instanceof B); // true
console.log(userObj instanceof A); //  Also true?
```

Answer (score 1):

Prototype object has a built in property called constructor.First see this image from chorme console than i will discuss

[image]

In your code `B.prototype = new A();` =>this statement sets B's prototype to a instance of A.So B's prototype object has it's constructor property assigned to A();

```
console.log(userObj.constructor // it will show A.But it is not true
```

Remember it is not userObj's constructor.The constructor you get is from prototype obj.

> console.log(userObj instanceof A); // true, How this can be true?

As userObj is a instance of B.And B inherits from A.So userObj is also a instance of A.But you can manipulate the constructor property set to B using

```
B.prototype.constructor=B;
```

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(userObj instanceof A);` you will surely get `true`. This is as per the JavaScript standard.

When you are creating a object of `B` which inherits all the properties of `A` , the object contains a link `__proto__` which points to `A's Prototype`.

So `instanceof` will find the `A's` constructor in the prototypical chaining of the Object `B`.

That's why it returns true.